# Comparison between residual intersection in Fulton's intersection theory and Aluffi's result on Milnor class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, characteristic-classes

$\textbf{Question}$ I deduced that $m(A \cup B, V) = 0 $ for nonsingular variety $V$ and nonsingular hyper surfaces $A$ and $B$ whose intersection is also nonsingular. But I do not think it is true compared to Aluffi's result. Can you help me to know which step is wrong?

- $m(A \cup B, V)$ is a Milnor class of $A \cup B \subset V$ which will be defined later.

p.161, Fulton, Intersection theory :
$\textbf{Proposition 9.2}$ Let $D \subset W \subset V$ be closed embeddings of schemes, with $V$ a k-dimensional variety, and $D$ is a Cartier divisor on V. Let $R$ be a residual scheme to $D$ in $W$. Then for all $m$,
$$ s(W, V)_m = s(D, V)_m + \sum_{j = 0}^{k-m} {k-m \choose j} (-D)^j \cdot s(R, V)_{m+j} $$
in $A_m(W)$.

My quesetion is here :
Let $V$ be a nonsingular projective variety.
Let $A$ and $B$ be two nonsingular hypersurfaces of $V$ and $D$ be the intersection of $A$ and $B$ which is also nonsingular. Let $\eta : \tilde{V} \to V$ be the blow up of $V$ along $D$ and denote $\tilde{D}$ by the inverse image of $D$ under $\eta$. Let $\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{B}$ be strict transforms of $A$ and $B$ under $\eta$. Note that $\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{B}$ does not intersect by the exercise 7.12 of Hartshorne ChapterII.
If the residual schemes to $\tilde{D}$ in $\eta^{-1}(A), \eta^{-1}(B)$ and $\eta^{-1}(A \cup B)$ are $\tilde{A}, \tilde{B}$ and $ \tilde{A} \sqcup \tilde{B} $, respectively, then we can apply $\textbf{Proposition 9.2}$ as follows :

$$ s(\eta^{-1}(A \cup B), \tilde{V}) = s(\tilde{D}, \tilde{V}) + \sum_{m \geq 0 } \sum_{j = 0}^{k-m} {k-m \choose j} (- \tilde{D}^j) \cdot s(\tilde{A} \sqcup \tilde{B}, \tilde{V})_{m+j}  $$
$$ s(\eta^{-1}(A), \tilde{V}) = s(\tilde{D}, \tilde{V}) + \sum_{m \geq 0 } \sum_{j = 0}^{k-m} {k-m \choose j} (- \tilde{D}^j) \cdot s(\tilde{A}, \tilde{V})_{m+j}  $$
$$ s(\eta^{-1}( B), \tilde{V}) = s(\tilde{D}, \tilde{V}) + \sum_{m \geq 0 } \sum_{j = 0}^{k-m} {k-m \choose j} (- \tilde{D}^j) \cdot s(\tilde{B}, \tilde{V})_{m+j}  $$

Since $s(\tilde{A} \sqcup \tilde{B}, \tilde{V})_l = s(\tilde{A}, \tilde{V})_l + s(\tilde{B}, \tilde{V})_l$ for all $l$, we have following :
$$ s(\eta^{-1}(A \cup B), \tilde{V}) + s(\tilde{D}, \tilde{V}) = s(\eta^{-1}(A), \tilde{V}) + s(\eta^{-1}(B), \tilde{V}) \cdots (*) $$
By taking $\eta_*$ we obtain
$$ s(A \cup B, V) + s(D , V) = s(A, V) + s(B, V) \cdots (**)$$ since $\tilde{D} = \eta^{-1}(D)$ and by $\textbf{Proposition 4.2, Fulton}$.

However this contradicts to Aluffi's result : ($\textbf{Aluffi 2003}$)

Let $X$ be a subvariety of nonsingular variety $M$. Chern-Fulton class $c_F(X)$ is defined by $c(T_M) \cap s(X, M)$. Since total Segre class for closed embedding $X \subset M$ does not satisfy the inclusion-exclusion principle for singular varieties, instead, Aluffi defined another class $s^{\circ}(X, M)$ given by $c_{SM}(X) = c(T_M) \cap s^{\circ}(X, M)$ where $c_{SM}(X)$ is the Chern-Schwartz-MacPherson class which satisfies the inclusion-exclusion principle for every algebraic varieties. Since $c_{SM}(X) = c_F(X)$ when $X$ is a nonsingular subvariety, $s^{\circ}(X, M) = s(X, M)$ in this case.
Aluffi defined the difference $s^{\circ}(X, M) - s(X, M)$ by $m(X, M)$ which is called by Milnor class. Especially, $m(X, M) = 0$ when $X$ is nonsingular. If $X$ is a hypersurface of $M$ and $Y$ is a singular scheme of $X$, we have following formular by Aluffi :
$$ m(X, M) = c(\mathcal{O}(X))^{-1} \cap (s(Y, M)\breve{} \otimes_M \mathcal{O}(X)) $$
The dual and tensor product notation are defined in $\textbf{Aluffi(1999)}$, section 1.4.

In my case, since $V, A, B$ and $D$ are nonsingular, $s^{\circ}(T, V) = s(T, V)$ where $T$ is one of $A, B$ and $D$. Thus $s(A \cup B, V) = s^{\circ}(A, V) + s^{\circ}(B, V) - s^{\circ}(D, V) = s^{\circ}( A \cup B, V)$.

Then $m(A \cup B, V) = 0$. However I do not think that $c(\mathcal{O}(A \cup B))^{-1} \cap (s(D, V)\breve{} \otimes_V \mathcal{O}(A \cup B))$ is zero for general hypersurfaces $A$ and $B$ such that whose intersection is also nonsingular.

........Which step is wrong.....